# Share Text, Image and Url on Google+ without login

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller, qquickitem, nsurlcomponents

I would like to share Image with Url on Google+ without login on my iOS app.

I have used :

```
NSString *temp = @"Hello World";

// Construct the Google+ share URL
NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]                                                      initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];
                urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
                                              initWithName:@"text"
                                              value:temp]];
NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];

if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
    // Open the URL in SFSafariViewController (iOS 9+)
    SFSafariViewController* controller = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]                                                               initWithURL:url];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {
    // Open the URL in the device's browser
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

I am not getting how to send Image with same Method ..

Comment: I am also facing issues for share only url, once it redirect me to safari it does not show POST button, it direct redirect me to Google Plus page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late to answer this question, but someone will be useful.

```
NSURL *shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/image.jpg"];
urlComponents.queryItems = @[
        [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"url" value:[shareURL absoluteString]],
        [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"text" value:text]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.1

```
 let strKeyValue: String =  "https://example.com/image.jpg"

guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://plus.google.com/share") else {
                return nil
   }    
 urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "url", value:strKeyValue),URLQueryItem(name: "text", value:"This is testing text")]

  let browserViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: urlComponents.url)

  browserViewController.delegate = self 

  present(browserViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please format the code so it displays as code, which is easiest done by making sure each line has at least four spaces indent? (I had a look myself wasn't sure how exactly the lines wrapped.) And can you explain the changes you had to make to make this Swift 4.1? Thanks!

Comment: There are not major changes in code but yes definitely syntax changes are there